# WIF entry point, federated authentication

Tags: wif, adfs2.0, federated-identity, adfs

In an asp.net application, is it possible to have only a handful of pages (.aspx) to be WIF protected while leaving the other pages untouched?

Basically, what I want is when the user land on the `HomePage.aspx`, they can browse and be able to go to `PageOption.aspx` and `PageAbout.aspx` - however when they try to access the `PageAccount.aspx` I want the WIF settings kicked in. And if the user is logged in already, then great - otherwise we redirect the user to an STS page where they can get authenticated.

Right now, all of my pages are WIF protected. So if I try to access any of the pages I get redirected to the STS page.

I have tried modifying the web.config file and putting the pages I want WIF protected in a separate folder and give its separate web.config, but no luck so far.

Also, I am getting error if I try to set the `<authentication mode..` in the nested web.config. Why can't I do that either?

The error I get is (on line 15):

> Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.
>
> Source Error:  Line 15:

Just to take it a step further to what I am trying to do is allow forms authentication on the `PageOption.aspx` and the `PageAbout.aspx` and when user tries to go directly to the `PageAccount.aspx` I want then to use federated authentication.

Any security gurus out there that can shed some light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed it is - use the location tag in web.config e.g. [Setting authorization rules for a particular page or folder in web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx).

Re. the authentication mode - what did you set - what are you trying to do - what error did you get?